# Testing RACSignals with XCTest

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm using the **MVVM** paradigm in my current iOS app. Recently, I have also started using `ReactiveCocoa` with the project. I've now moved onto experimenting with `Unit testing` as well.

The problem I am facing is how to correctly test the custom `RACSignal`s I have created. Here is an example of a test signal I am testing. This signal is used with a `UItextField` and will stop unwanted characters being entered into the textField. In this case, I am only allowing numbers:

```
//Declared like so:
-(RACSignal *)onlyAllowNumbersforTextFieldSignal:(RACSignal *)signal

//used like this: 
 RAC(testTextField, text) = [self.viewModel onlyAllowNumbersforTextFieldSignal:testTextField.rac_textSignal];
```

Now the signal works perfectly in the `viewModel` and in the `viewController` - I now just want to create a `test case` for these sorts of signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `+[RACSignal return:]` method to provide an input signal (instead of the text field's one). Then use `-first` method to get the value of the output signal from the view model:

```
- (void)testExample {
  RACSignal *textSignal = [RACSignal return:@"a123"];
  //assuming that you initialized self.viewModel in setUp method of your test case
  NSString *result = [[self.viewModel onlyAllowNumbersforTextFieldSignal:textSignal] first];
  XCTAssertEqualObjects(result, @"123");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will give it ago as soon as I get some time to carry on with test cases. If only I could have awarded you the bounty.! Will also update once I have tested this fully.